# How do you only display the "Total" column in SQL results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL, and I keep running this code and it shows the Price, Amount, and Total Column. I only need to see the total column with the calculations in it.

```
      SELECT 
         price,
         amount,
  price * amount AS total
  FROM items;
```

How do I fix my code to only display the "total" column?

Comment: Any column in your `SELECT` will be included in the result set.  If you don't want to see it, you just exclude it from your `SELECT` statement.  `SELECT price * amount AS total FROM items;`

Answer (score 2):

You are telling SQL to bring back all three based on your select statement.
Change it to as follows:

```
SELECT price * amount AS Total
FROM items;
```

Comment: No problem, just remember that you do not have to show (bring back) a field to do a calculation on it. You can do any manipulation you please on the query itself as you have done above.